# JComboBox mouseClicked on cell

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to call a function when a user clicks (with the mouse) on an item in a JComboBox; however, I don't want this event fired for any keyboard events - I only want this fired for a click on a particular cell of the dropdown (I know about addActionListener and addItemListener, but these are fired for more events than I want).

EDIT: I should have specified that mouseClicked doesn't work either -  no events seem to be fired (however, they were at one point but when that happened, they fired for clicks on the text field as well), but I thought that was assumed from the title.

I have also tried the solution given here (also doesn't work): [Editable JCombobox mouseclicked event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330854/editable-jcombobox-mouseclicked-event-not-working)

EDIT2:  I tried the following, but still no output on click:

```
try {
    Field popupInBasicComboBoxUI = BasicComboBoxUI.class.getDeclaredField("popup");
    popupInBasicComboBoxUI.setAccessible(true);
    BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup)popupInBasicComboBoxUI.get(attachedCB.getUI());

    Field scrollerInBasicComboPopup = BasicComboPopup.class.getDeclaredField("scroller");
    scrollerInBasicComboPopup.setAccessible(true);
    JScrollPane scroller = (JScrollPane)scrollerInBasicComboPopup.get(popup);

    scroller.getViewport().getView().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseClicked(e);
        System.out.println("nope");
      }
    });
  }
  catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: You need to add the mouseListener to the Popup not the JComboBox as the example states here: http://engin-tekin.blogspot.com/2009/10/hrefhttpkfd.html  Did you try this one and it didn't work?  If so where you using a different LAF?

Comment: See EDIT2, didn't work :(

Comment: Try adding the listener to the JList from popup.getList()

Comment: See my last answer.  Add it to the scrollPane's viewport view as stated in the link.  Just ran the demo of the link and it worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed adding it to the scrollPane's viewport view in the link I posted in the comments.

```
Field scrollerInBasicComboPopup = BasicComboPopup.class.getDeclaredField("scroller");
scrollerInBasicComboPopup.setAccessible(true);
JScrollPane scroller = (JScrollPane) scrollerInBasicComboPopup.get(popup);
scroller.getViewport().getView().addMouseListener(listener);
```

Comment: I had tried that, still no; the full code is in EDIT2

Comment: I don't get a mouseClicked either but I get a mousePressed and mouseReleased event.  You will need to use those.  Change your mouseAdapter to use the mousePressed and/or mouseReleased methods.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
jComboBox.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jComboBoxMouseClicked(evt);//your logic here
            }            
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is exactly what I have tried...  Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **java.awt.event.ActionEvent**, which is (quoted from javadoc) a

> semantic event which indicates that a component-defined action
>   occurred. This high-level event is generated by a component (such as a
>   Button) when the component-specific action occurs (such as being
>   pressed)...

like this:

```
        jComboBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                javax.swing.JComboBox source = (javax.swing.JComboBox)evt.getSource();
                // use getSelectedIndex to know the item if needed
                labelTextField.setText(source.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
        });
```

Note **getSelectedItem** and **getSelectedIndex** and **getSelectedObjects** methods : this  allows you to know which item has been selected and process only the items you want

Comment: This fires on keyboard events as well, which is unacceptable.